# How can i get the URL of the page that used "require_once"

Tags: php, require-once

I created a PHP site that has 3 pages, i.e., A, B, and C. Both A and B will call page C first by using "require_once". Is there a way for page C to know if this call came from A or B?

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` didn't work.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why exactly do you need to know?  And how much do you need to know?  Do you only need to differentiate between the two or must you be able to pinpoint which one exactly?

Comment: put a tag in A and B, like $tag = "A.php";

Answer (score 2):

A.php

```
$page = 'A';
require_once 'C.php';
```

B.php

```
$page = 'B';
require_once 'C.php';
```

C.php

```
echo 'I was required by'.$page;
```

Comment: This means `$page` variable needs to be available on all three pages.

Comment: Yes, same for the require() call

Comment: Your solution is only applicable if the number of files is small. Otherwise, it takes too long to include the initialization of $page in each file...

Comment: It takes the same amount of time of using the require_once(); if the number of pages grows bigger OP could go for another approach, something like a "fron controller", which will handle the $page determination as well. Anyway, simple answer for simple question ('site that has 3 pages')

Answer (score 2):

You can use debug_backtrace function in **c.php**
You will get caller file and caller line nos as well.

```
$db =  debug_backtrace();

echo "Calling file: ". $db[0]['file'] . ' line  '. $db[0]['line'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. Per php.net,

> URI provides the entire request path (/directory/file.ext?query=string)

Comment: Thanks. This is the way i was looking for cuz i didn't want to put any extra variable in the calling pages. Sorry i don't have enough reputation to vote up.